# Hi, I am getting the parameter is incorrect error for following code in certutil

Tags: certutil

I am new to certutil and I am getting the following error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
certutil -view -restrict
```

> “Disposition=20,notafter=>1/17/2014,Certificate
>   Template=<1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.8.1370017.958360.9715892.10314310.367570.155.3464656.3414923>”
>   -out “Request.RequesterName,CommonName,NotAfter”

Comment: Post the error please

Comment: PS C:\Users\admpravima> certutil -view -restrict "Disposition=20,notafter=>1/17/2014,Certificate Template=1.3.6.1.4.1.31
1.21.8.1370017.958360.9715892.10314310.367570.155.3464656.3414923" -out "RequestID,RequesterName,CommonName,NotAfter"
CertUtil: -view command FAILED: 0x80070057 (WIN32: 87)
CertUtil: The parameter is incorrect.
PS C:\Users\admpravima>

Comment: this is the first time i am asking question..i didn't know.

Answer (score 0):

[Refer to link. It will fix the issue.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/3041857/-code-0x80070057-the-parameter-is-incorrect-error-when-you-try-to-display-a-user-s-effective-access-to-a-file)

This is because of windows update and not a problem with your code.